# No service for type <TYPE> has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I am working on a asp.net core mvc project and trying to inject a database object to the view to retrieve something from it inside the view.

I injected the class into the startup.cs and used the @inject  but still I get the exception.

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'DbServices.CredentialDb' has been registered.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
```

This is the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
        options => options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(
            _config.GetConnectionString("AutoLoverDbConnection"), 
            x => x.MigrationsAssembly("AutoMatcherProjectAss"))
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISessionManager, ClientSIdeSessionManager>();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSession();
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies
        // is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); //You can set Time   
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });
    services.AddTransient<ISche, SchedulerImpl>();
    services.AddTransient<IQueue, QueueImpl>();
    services.AddTransient<SchedulerJob>();
    services.AddTransient<IBotFactory, BotFactory>();
    services.AddTransient<ICredentialDb, CredentialDb>();
    services.AddSingleton(provider => _scheduler);
    services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = APP_ID;
        options.AppSecret = APP_SECRET;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
    _scheduler.Clear();
}
```

this is where I added the database access class:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ICredentialDb, CredentialDb>();
```

and these are the injections in the HTML view page:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using DbServices

@inject CredentialDb DataAccess
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> signIn
```

Comment: It's been registered as the interface so: `@inject ICredentialDb DataAccess`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is to use interface for injection and concrete class to resolve it.

```
services.AddTransient<ICredentialDb, CredentialDb>();
```

[AddTransient(IServiceCollection)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddTransient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) adds a transient service of the type `ICredentialDb` ith an implementation type `CredentialDb` to the specified IServiceCollection. You can resolve your service by service type like in the code below:

```
@inject ICredentialDb DataAccess
```